# Nginx proxy don't work for localhost on port 81 - Always 502 (bad gateway)

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a simple web application running in a docker container and exposed on port 81.
`curl http://127.0.0.1:81` returns the index.html of that web app. So it is running and is reachable.
Also *localhost* or using the browser it works.

Now I added a container with Nginx.
I want to redirect the calls to port 80 to the web app.
This is my simplest */etc/nginx/nginx.conf* file:

```
events {}
http {
    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81;            
            #proxy_pass http://google.com;
        }
    }
}
```

Switching the proxy_pass to the one pointing to Google it works, so I assume the error is because nginx is not able to "communicate" with the web app (also that is what I read about nginx and 502 error).

I access to the nginx instance with `docker -it <container-name> /bin/bash` but then
`cat /var/log/nginx/error.log` or `cat /var/log/nginx/access.log` or *tail* doesn't work (kind of enter in edit mode but there is no content).

After this simple step is done I'd like to use upstream to ahave a load balancer over 2 web app instances, so something like this:

```
events {}

http {
    upstream api {
        server 127.0.0.1:81;
    }

    server {
        listen 80 default;
        #listen [::]:80;
        #access_log /dev/stdout;

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        location / {
            #proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:81;            
            #proxy_pass http://google.com;
            proxy_pass http://api;                       
            
            proxy_redirect     off;
        }
    }
}
```

Again, this does not work.

Comment: At first glance your problem appears that for an application running inside a container the localhost/127.0.0.1 address effectively means *"this container"* and not *"this server"*.   For your nginx container to connect to another container (running on the same server) you need to connect to either the public/external IP-address where the port is exposed of you set up a container network where the nginx can connect directly to the web application.